# Non-local returns from constructs that do not have a call stack entry

Tags: rust, return, language-design

I'm implementing named non-local returns in an AST interpreter written in Rust, and I have principles for closure NLR laid out. However, I'd like *all* expressions to support being labeled and returned from.

Basic pseudocode example for closure NLR:

```
a: fn {
  b: fn {
    return 'hello' from a;
  }
  
  b();
  
  vacuum_decay();
}

print(a()); // hello
```

The naive approach is to walk up the stack and return from the first instance of the corresponding function. But take this example:

```
let x;

a: fn {
  if x != null {
    x();
  } else {
    a(fn {
      return 'hello' from a; // naive approach would immediately return from the parent here and the universe goes poof. my approach uses lexical scope to determine where to return from
    });
    
    vacuum_decay();
  }
}

print(a()); // hello
```

The implementation assigns two ids:

- Identity, a compile time id that every closure gets
- Generation, a runtime id that every instance of a closure gets (when the closure expression is evaluated)

Closure instances contain a map of Identity IDs to Generation IDs for all NLRs they contain

Return expressions get the identity to return from at compile time, and at runtime they look up the generation id to return from, then throw a fake NLR "exception" with the identity and generation that gets caught by the call system.

All this is good, but I don't quite know how to implement NLRs for expressions that aren't functions.

```
let x = a: someFunction(if someCondition {
  return 'hello' from a;
} else { null }, vacuum_decay());

print(x); // hello
```

And the naive approach mentioned earlier would still be different from the desired result here too:

```
let x;

while someCondition {
  a: {
    if someOtherCondition {
      x(); // should throw an error because the context that x was created in has gone out of scope (a different generation of `a` exists). the naive approach would not throw an error as to it, `a` still exists
    } else {
      x = fn { return from a; }
    }
  }
}
```

How should I go about implementing this? The current system relies on having each closure invocation on the call stack and being able to index those, but I feel that would be inefficient to do for every single expression and it would interfere with how variables work.

So far I'm thinking of options:

- Abandon NLRs for expressions (I'd rather not)
- Make expression NLRs use the naive approach and not care about generations, just return to the nearest target. (Could cause confusion since it's two different systems meshed as one)
- Make ALL NLRs use the naive approach (I'd rather not)
- Solve the issue (that's why we're here :3)

Comment: What about passing as a hidden argument the stack frame pointer and the ip of the expression / function to the closure when it is built, at runtime. Then, doing a NLR means storing in a register the ip, deallocate the stack to return to the remembered stack frame pointer, then jump to the remembered ip?

Comment: @jthulhu I'm writing an AST interpreter at the moment (although bytecode interpreter is planned, it's not a priority rn)